# Unable to access object values in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I have this code :https://jsfiddle.net/afelipeor/o2qqt7ux/ and I need to be able to access the values in the object, and display the text in the html, as it is for a multi-language website. However, I can't seem to be able to, and all my research showed is that I'm declaring everything correctly.

As long as the value I need is not in a object, it works, so I know that I'm not doing things completely wrong. For example, if I create `$scope.text = 'text';` and access it with `{{ text }}`, it works as it should.

However, I must be doing something wrong. Does anyone know what?

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the code in your question

Comment: @LionC, I put the fiddle, because the relevant code is big enough to clutter the question.

Comment: Then create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Stackoverflow also has its own integrated way of creating demos (code snippets). This way your question will (always) be self-contained and helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your fiddle, your data is nested in an array.

```
$scope.english = [
    {
        home: "home",
        about: "About Template",
        services: "Services",
        contact: "Contact",
        eng:"English",
        ptg: "Portuguese"
    }
];
```

You can get it to display properly like this:

```
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">{{english[0].home}}</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">{{english[0].about}}</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">{{english[0].services}}</a></li>
                <li>
                    <select id="navLang">
                        <option >{{english[0].eng}}</option>
                        <option>{{english[0].ptg}}</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. The fiddle continued to display the same output it would before.

Comment: @AndreFelipe I recommend to look at the console output of your js fiddle. There is more than one error there

Comment: @LionC Thanks, I hadn't thought to check since my original code had none. turns out that buzzsaw was right. The problem was that it was in a array, which for me is odd, since all the examples I've seen online were as well, and didn't specify the index